# How to get Rootnode Element attribute value in a xml File

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0

I want to read a Rootnode element attribute value ,but my code is not working.my code

```
XML:
      <Datatable Name="AS1" Type="table">
        <Table>
           <Column Name="ID" Type="uniqueidentifier">
           </Column>
        </Table>
      </Datatable>
```

Code:

```
            XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(path);
            var q = (from c in doc.Elements("Datatable")
                    select new
                    {
                        dID = c.Attribute("Name"),

                    }).ToList(); 

          var on = new Ton()
             {

                Name=q[0].dID.ToString(),
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now
             };
```

So i need to pass the selected rootnode attribute value to the Name object.
but when i trying with this code q has return count=0.
can anyone please help to get a rootnode value?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you are loading the wrong file?

Comment: i got the error in Name=q[0].....like Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: The code is fine. Something else is the problem. Check the path you load the file from. Verify that it really has a node `Datatable` and not something like `DataTable`...

Comment: my first line is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>          next is my rootnode,it has some Namespaces also like xmlns,xsi , is there any problem with this?

Comment: Yes, namespaces must be added before tag names. Please show the first lines.

Comment: @Ash: How do you expect to get competent help if you don't show the XML you really have?? Please do so now, show us your XML.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> - <Datatable Name="AS1" Type="table" xmlns="http://kd.gnp.com/Model/1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://kd.gnp.com/Model/1.0 Model.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> - <Table> <Column Name="ID" Type="uniqueidentifier"> <Property Name="Constraint" Value="NOT NULL" /> </Column> ......like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the start of your code :

```
XNamespace xn = "kd.gnp.com/Model/1.0";
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(path);
            var q = (from c in doc.Elements(xn +"Datatable")
```

... same